# horizontal bands on sony Ar7ii (some photos)

Tags: sony-alpha, sony-a7ii

recently I acquired a sony ar7ii and have done about 2k photos with it. 
works amazingly, but occasionally i see these black bands.

i have no idea what is causing it, and how to prevent it. any insight would be appreciated!  [image: (]

Comment: Related: [How can one correct intensity flicker due to AC line frequency?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/59454)

Answer (score 2):

**The horizontal light and dark bands looks like a flickering issue**, which is common with many artificial light sources. Some cameras have an anti-flickering setting. If such a setting is *not* available, you can try dropping the shutter speed to something like 1/40. If the problem goes away, you can gradually increase the shutter speed until just before banding reappears.

The problem is often associated with **electronic rolling shutter**. Unfortunately, the solution would be to adjust the *readout time*, which is out of your control.

Here is another effect associated with electronic rolling shutters:

- YouTube: [Rolling shutter vs. global shutter: guitar string deformation](https://youtu.be/Dk6o5RAIaj4)

[image]

**Related Questions:**

- [What causes a band-like pattern in photos of a CFL?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/24554/75526)
- [Pink and green lines on shots](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/95794/75526)
- [Canon 5D Mark III - problems with fluorescent light](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/25429/75526)
- [What causes these inconsistent dark bands in some of my photos from an indoor event?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99456/75526)
- [Do fluorescent lighting and shutter speed create a problem with color cast?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4115/75526)
- [What causes neon sign light to smudge like this?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/107954/75526)
- [How can one correct intensity flicker due to AC line frequency?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/59454/75526)

Comment: thanks!!! i've also noticed this effect outside, but it was at night so possibly caused by one of the street lights ?

Comment: +1 for amazing info! but the other answer suggest possible solutions which appear to be reasonable :)

Comment: Banding at night could be street lights, but would have to see the picture. Camera settings would also be helpful.

Comment: I don't think the other answer is entirely accurate. At best, it contains some red herrings, such as the link to banding caused by fixed-pattern noise. Did you actually try the "solutions" to see if they work? *Not* marking an accepted answer is also an option.

Comment: no i have not tried those things yet, answer unmarked

Answer (score 1):

The banding seems similar to that from "rolling shutter", where parts of the image sensor are scanned sequentially during the [flickering of fluorescent and LED lighting](https://photographylife.com/light-frequency-issue).

A few ways to avoid, or at least reduce, the problem:

- Use fill light from a source that doesn't flicker, such as daylight or incandescent lamps.
- Use a flash, either direct or bounced.
- Adjust the shutter speed to get a full cycle of AC power, which is 50 Hz in many countries, but 60 Hz in North America. I.E., Use 1/25 or 1/50 second most places, 1/30 or 1/60 second in N. A.

Experiment taking photos with your camera of a plain white surface lit by fluorescent or LED lamps, using different shutter speeds, to confirm if that is the issue and to see how best to fix it. *N.B.* Some LED lamps are more prone to flicker than others. Also, some fluorescent tube phosphors have longer persistence than others, so you might observe slightly *colored* bands.

This may be similar to [another question about banding](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41874/what-causes-banding-noise-in-cmos-sensors), though.

Comment: Using flash won't *fix* the banding problem in this question. Flash can also have its own [banding problems](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/65372/75526). The banding in this Q is not at all related to banding caused by fixed-pattern noise.